# Can't read nfc tag in foregorund mode

Tags: android, tags, nfc, foreground, dispatch

I need to choose my activity when phone read a tag. My app should be visible on activity chooser.

In manifest file of my activity, i have

```
        <activity android:name=".WaitingPayment" android:noHistory="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

In the activity class i have:

```
nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    ndef = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
    try {
        ndef.addDataType("*/*");    /* Handles all MIME based dispatches. 
                                       You should specify only the ones that you need. */
    }
    catch (MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("fail", e);
    }
    this.intentFiltersArray = new IntentFilter[] {ndef};
    this.techListsArray = new String[][] { new String[] { MifareUltralight.class.getName(), Ndef.class.getName(), NfcA.class.getName()}};
```

What i can do to see my tag on activity chooser and handle it? My tag it's a URI

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you could try this for a URI:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="http"
        android:host="developer.android.com"
        android:pathPrefix="/index.html" />
</intent-filter>
```

This would be the appropriate way to detect a URI type Ndef. Your code is looking for MIME type. The biggest thing to look for is the TYPE of Ndef record you have.

You could use this link for more information in this regard: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/nfc.html

Answer (score 0):

Your code is using foreground dispatching, which is unnecessary. Just use the intent filter. If your application is the only one filtering for that URI, it will launch automatically. If there are multiple applications that can handle the URI, your app will appear in the activity launcher. You do not need the second code snippet, just the snippet in Ben's answer and modify it for your URI.

Answer (score 0):

The Activity Chooser appears only if there are more than 1 application having the same intent filter.As you have Uri written to your Tag you should use

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
<data android:scheme="http"
     android:host="developer.android.com"
     android:pathPrefix="/index.html" />
</intent-filter>
```